# Workflow steps with configuration setup UI

Tags: tables, inline-edit

I have an application where users can setup workflow steps. The workflow setup is a editable table with a field for configuration. The issue I have is with this field. This field has some JSON snippet. And, since it is in a table column the user doesn't see the full information and the edit area is very small.

Any suggestions on how to build a better UI where the information in the configuration field is visible for the user and there is enough space to edit.
[image]

Comment: what do you have now? please post a mockup so we can visualize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a modal to paste or edit JSON would be one of the options, instead of doing it inline.

Firebase has a nice inline editing workflow – it's material, so they add a large input on top of the field, it's elevated 1 lvl above previous content, and has an explicit Save button, despite not being presented as a modal component (no scrim, etc).

[image: Firebase inline modal-ish example]